# cloud function running in worker poll needs to download code artifact dependencies

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a problem that I really can't find a solution I have a cloud function in GCP that I create with the command.

```
gcloud functions deploy function --gen2 --runtime=java11 --region=southamerica-east1 --source=. --entry-point=br.com.div.divfunction.listeners.PubsubFunctionListener --memory=512MB --trigger-http
```

the build of this function is done in a gcp cloud build workerpool, but recently the function needs to access the aws codeartifact to download some dependencies.

```
<repositories>
<repository>
 <id>releases</id>
  <name>aws</name>
  <url>https://div-domain-repositories-xxxxxxxxxx.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mvn/div_releases/</url>
</repository>
```

it is returning me the error
Could not transfer artifact br.com.div:log-task-model:pom:0.2.0 from/to releases (https://div-domain-repositories-xxxxxxxxxx.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws. com/mvn/div_releases/): status code: 403, reason phrase: Forbidden (403) -> [Help 1]"

Because I need to configure access to the artificat code with aws cli in the worker, is there any way to access this worker or his image to do this configuration?

Thanks...